# sftp copy files from windows server to linux server using shell scripting

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I am working on shell script that is supposed to transfer files (with their subdirectories) from a Windows Server to a Linux-Samba server.  The Windows server is setup to accept sftp requests and I am logging into the Windows server with shared ssh keys so there is no need for a password exchange.  I can log into the Windows from the linux server with this command:

```
    sftp user@host_name
```

It executes the sftp command and logs me into the Windows server.  When I try to use the:

```
    get -r /home_directory/first_level/* /local/directory/to/put/files
```

I get an error message saying "Invalid flag -r".  I can't use SCP because it is not enabled on the server.

What can I do in order to recursively copy all the files and directories from the Windows server to the linux server using a shell script?

Comment: Is `rsync` available? if the remote server allows installed keys for passwords, I don't see how it is security risk (any greater) to allow recursive `sftp` copies (maybe someone will comment if there are greater risks). Did you ask if you can get the `-r` enabled? Otherwise you're going to have to pull dir listings, compare timestamps/sizes, only pull changed or new files. A real headache! Your time will be well spent at least raising this as a serious issue to whoever is paying you. Good luck!

Comment: Our department IT says that `-r` is enabled and they can use it just fine with windows...well the problem is my entire environment is linux and not windows.

Comment: After rereading, I see I assumed wrongly how you are using sftp. I would just do `sftp -r user@remhost remhostname:/path/to/dir/files/* /local/dir/` (I don't have access to `man sftp` right now so order of args may need changing and maybe it is `-R`). Good luck.

Comment: Finally, there are other utils that can transfer files. But recursive is always a question mark. `lftp` is very interesting and a ton of features, but its probably not installed on your windows servers. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks these are all good tips.  I'll post once I've had a chance to see what works best.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) onto your Windows server and initiate an `scp -r` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us a bigger snippet of the script?

Also, the `get` keyword is part of `sftp` lingo, are you doing something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp -v -oIdentityFile=path user@server<<-_EOF_
    get -r /home/dir/first_level/* /local/dir/to/put/files
    bye
_EOF_

# etc etc
```

Comment: I was only using
       sftp user@host <<-_EOF_
       get -r /home/dir/first/* /local/dir/to/put/files
I'm going to try rsync and your tip and see what comes up.

Comment: Lets leave confusion on the side. Your question was can you recursively copy files and directories from a remote sftp enabled server from a shell script. The answer is yes, you can. You can connect via sftp using a script, and execute `sftp` commands with a here file, like in the code snippet above.